# NVIDIA drivers stretching out the desktop?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. My video card is G Force GTX 560TI and it's connected to HDTV LG RZ37LZ55. When using the default Linux driver, everything looks fine on res 1360x768.

However, when I install Nvidia drivers, the desktop is stretch out to the point that I can't see or use the sidebar, nor can I see the top panel. Changing the resolution to higher or lower does not pan the screen correctly. It is always stretched out. I am a total newbie in Linux so most things I've tried ended in crashing the system, for example adding horizontal and vertical refresh rates to xorg.conf.

I can fit the screen using the Nvidia X settings but that makes the desktop all blurry. I'm using an older TV (conected via DVI) and I don't have the option to chagne the borderlines in the TV menu. Could anybody help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run nvidia-settings

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

Use twinview. If you are able to configure your resolution from there, save teh settings to xorg.conf, do NOT merge with the existing file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm afraid this won't be helpful as twinview is greyed out for me, thus I cannot select it. I'm not using a laptop conected to the TV, rather a PC and the TV working as a monitor. Is there eny other way to solve this issue? BTW I'm using a 64bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: If nvidia-settings does not resolve the problem, you might be able to write a xorg.conf manually. xorg.conf is somewhat depreciated, and you can often skip most of it, and simply write a section for your display. You can post your xorg.conf and the technical specifications of your monitor (pastebin please) and I will try to review it.

Comment: Hi, this is my xorg.conf after installing the driver: http://pastebin.com/LrA43tr1   And this is the TV i'm using: http://www.onyougo.com/lg-rz-27lz55-rz-27lz55-lcd-tvs_pi748760  not many specs there but it's hard to find anything on it. Hope you find this helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi again, I searched the net but still haven't been able to come up with a solution. Your editing of xconf.org really sparked a light of hope for me. Could you please help me in this subject?

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, That is true that Nvidia has a problem with Ubuntu kernels. But with the latest releases of their driver, it can be resolved. For instance, I could not change my screen resolution but I went to

software updates/additional drivers

and then change it to latest Nvidia driver(mine was Nvidia396) and after applying changes it worked flawlessly.